# Search and remove the specific string from url using .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

Using `.htaccess` apache rewrite I'm looking to remove subfolder/substring from the my url. For now it looks like:

```
www.domain.com/store/products.php`
```

and I want to change it to:

```
www.domain.com/products.php
```

How can i do it using `.htaccess` apache rewrite?

Comment: What code do you have? Please post.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with the root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^store/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change `[R=302]` for `[R=301]` when test work well.

Answer (score 1):

You need [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). A rule will be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myapp/
RewriteRule ^/store/products\.php$ /products.php
```

Or, for many different files, e.g. `products.php`, `places.php`, `blablabla.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myapp/
RewriteRule ^/store/([a-z]+)\.php$ /$1.php
```

That depends on what URLs you want to rewrite. You should read the docs.

## All-matching .htaccess rule

Also, I'd suggest you to use the following `catch all URLs` pattern. It will redirect any path to `index.php`. This is widely used in a lot of CMS systems to give you ability to perform dynamic routing with `PHP`:

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QS
```

### index.php

```
<?php

$path = isset($_GET['path']) ? explode('/', $_GET['path']) : array();

// If you navigate to /foo/bar/dead/beef, yur $path var will be like:
// $path == array ( 0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar', 2 => 'dead', 3 => 'beef' );

?>
```

Comment: how it could be if i have two or more subfolder in the /store?

Comment: http://atop.msidevelopment.com/store/46-poe-switches will you check here...      I want to remove /store from all url